# Swiper with Sveltekit: no "swiping"

Tags: svelte, swiper.js, sveltekit

I have tried to use swiper 6.8.0 with sveltekit 1.0.0-next.137.
I have installed swiper with `npm i swiper`.
There is a detailed description how to use swiper at the end of this page:
https://swiperjs.com/svelte

This is the code:

```
<script>
  import SwiperCore, { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper';
  /* Import Swiper and SwiperSlide components from .svelte files */
  import Swiper from 'swiper/esm/svelte/swiper.svelte';
  import SwiperSlide from 'swiper/esm/svelte/swiper-slide.svelte';
</script>

<!-- Pass core modules in "modules" prop -->
<Swiper modules="{[ Navigation, Pagination ]}">
  <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
  <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>   
</Swiper>
```

Result: there is no "swipe-effect", no error messages.

I have put this example to the sandbox (with svelte, not with sveltekit):
https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-engelbart-tj8ub?file=/App.svelte

Comment: Awwwwwww, maaaaaaan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the replies and comments. I have updated to swiper 6.8.1 and added another . Now everything works as desired. Maybe the complete program will help someone.

```
<script>
    /* Import Swiper and SwiperSlide components from .svelte files  */
    import Swiper from 'swiper/esm/svelte/swiper.svelte';
    import SwiperSlide from 'swiper/esm/svelte/swiper-slide.svelte';

    import { Autoplay, Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper/core';

    import "swiper/swiper.min.css";
    import "swiper/components/pagination/pagination.min.css";
    import "swiper/components/navigation/navigation.min.css";
  
    const items = [
    {
      name: "Leonardo",
      age: 26,
      location: "Italy"
    },
    {
      name: "Maria",
      age: 27,
      location: "Brazil"
    },
    {
      name: "Oliver",
      age: 28,
      location: "United States"
    },
    {
      name: "Margarida",
      age: 29,
      location: "Portugal"
    }
    ];
    

</script>

<style>
    #swiper-container {
        width: 50vw;
        height: 300px;
    }
</style>

<div id="swiper-container">
    <Swiper 
        loop={true}
        spaceBetween={0}
        slidesPerView={1}
        autoplay={{
            delay: 1000,
            disableOnInteraction: true
        }}
        navigation={true}
        pagination={true}
        modules={[Autoplay, Navigation, Pagination]}
    >
      {#each items as item, i}
        <SwiperSlide>
          <div style="padding: 30px 8px; text-align: center; background: #ECE; border-radius: 5px;">
            <strong>{item.name}</strong> ({item.age})
            from {item.location}
          </div>
        </SwiperSlide>
      {/each}
    </Swiper>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been adressed on here: https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/4574
and then fixed here: https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/pull/4768

You can check out the demo that slava-viktorov made:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sveltekit-swiper-forked-iin8p?file=/src/routes/index.svelte

For me, i tried to implement the "*EffectCoverflow*" and the only solution was to put this: https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/4574#issuecomment-852646322 inside a component called **"Swiper.svete"**, then inside the **"index.svelte"**, add:

```
<script context="module" lang="ts">
import Swiper from '../lib/components/Swiper.svelte';

import SwiperCore, { Autoplay, EffectCoverflow, Navigation } from 'swiper/core';
SwiperCore.use([Autoplay, EffectCoverflow, Navigation]);
</script>

<Swiper />
```

I hope that this solution is any help for you.
I'm sorry for the edits, i'm only trying to give a good answer.

Comment: Thank you. No, that does not solve the problem. "svelte" and "sveltekit" apparently require different code. That's why I pointed out where the code example came from: at the bottom of the https://swiperjs.com/svelte page there is this example for sveltekit, but it just doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did my last answer solve your issue? maybe i forgot something...

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm only answering now. On the one hand, I was still working on another issue. On the other hand, I haven't worked with codesandboy enough and couldn't get the example 
at https://codesandbox.io/s/sveltekit-swiper-forked-iin8p?file=/src/routes/index.svelte to work with my data.

Thanks for the github example, I will try it next. But shouldn't this work a little easier? "i wanna learn  why this works : https://codesandbox.io/s/h91ee
but this does not : https://codesandbox.io/s/5jix6" interests me too.

Comment: yes, it was my bad on that, i found that method afther i responded here, i mean, i responded here with a example of code that worked on dev, and then when i was going to build it, i found it was an incomplete answer... there is also the thing that im not knowing if you are using that exact effect or not. This is my first answer on Stackoverflow, so, im sorry for everything.